# Obtaining OracleConnection from ComboPooledDataSource

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, jdbc

I have a ComboPooledDataSource in my java code - served up via tomcat JNDI.

What I need is to get at the OracleConnection connection (to register for DCN)

No matter what I try I cannot seem to achieve this.

I can easily get a com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection but this is apparently not a wrapper for OracleConnection. So for instance you can't just do

```
(OracleConnection)newProxyConnection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
```

Any help appreciated- I have been at this for many hours now..
Thanking you in advance

Comment: Which version of c3p0 are you using? According to [this](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#raw_connection_ops) you need at least 0.9.5 to be able to unwrap. It also provides alternatives. Note that needing to unwrap is usually an indication of something being wrong. You might want to describe what you are trying to achieve.